# Count highest ammount of consecutive field occurrencies

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

On a collection like this:

```js
db.consFieldTest.insert([
    { status : "err" }
    { status : "suc" }
    { status : "res" }
    { status : "res" }
    { status : "err" }
    { status : "err" }
    { status : "err" }
]);
```

The aggregation result should look like this:

```js
              { status: "err", maxCons : 3 },
// (optional) { status: "suc", maxCons : 1 },
// (optional) { status: "res", maxCons : 2 }
```

Actually it would be ok if the `maxCons` counter stops at 3, I need to know whether the `err` status has 3 or more consecutive occurrences.

**An idea to solve it:**

I thought about an workaround adding an increment on all documents like this:

```js
{ status : "err", id : 0 },
{ status : "suc", id : 1 },
{ status : "res", id : 2 },
{ status : "res", id : 3 },
{ status : "err", id : 4 },
{ status : "err", id : 5 },
{ status : "err", id : 6 }
```

And then group them in ranges like 0-2, 1-3, 2-4, ... 
That would lead into this:

```js
{   _id : 0 
    res : [
        { status : "err", id : 0 },
        { status : "suc", id : 1 },
        { status : "res", id : 2 }
    ]
},
{   _id : 1
    res : [
        { status : "suc", id : 1 },
        { status : "res", id : 2 },
        { status : "res", id : 3 },
    ]
},
{
    _id : 2
    res : [
        { status : "res", id : 2 },
        { status : "res", id : 3 },
        { status : "err", id : 4 },
    ]
} ...
```

Having this I could count how often the status `err` occurred in a consecutive order.
But I haven no Idea how to write this `group` stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with approaching this as an [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) problem is that there is no actual concept of comparing one document to another as all operations either work on a single document at a time or as a result of grouping the documents together.

So finding the "consecutive" entries is something that you need a "global" variable space for that can work across documents. There is nothing for the aggregation framework that does this, but the problem can be solved with [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/):

```
db.consFieldTest.mapReduce(
    function() {
        if ( lastSeen != this.status ) {
            lastSeen = this.status;
            list = [];
            counter = 0;
        }

        list.push(this._id);
        counter++;
        emit(lastSeen,{ "list": list, "count": counter });

    },
    function(key,values) {
        var mapped = values.map(function(x) { return x.count });
        return values[mapped.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math,mapped))];
    },
    { 
        "scope": { "lastSeen": null, "list": [], "counter": 0 },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

Put simply, this will emit a "key" for the current "status" value while keeping globals of "list" and "counter" which are tracking the consecutive occurrences. The lists will build up here, just using numeric values in the `_id` as an example, but could be anything:

```
    { "_id": "err", "values": { "list": [1], "count": 1 }}
    { "_id": "suc", "values": { "list": [2], "count": 1 }}
    { "_id": "res", "values": { "list": [3], "count": 1 }}
    { "_id": "res", "values": { "list": [3,4], "count": 2 }}
    { "_id": "err", "values": { "list": [5], "count": 1 }}
    { "_id": "err", "values": { "list": [5,6], "count": 2 }}
    { "_id": "err", "values": { "list": [5,6,7], "count":3 }}
```

That is essentially what gets emitted from the mapper. Note the build up from the globals there.

In the reduce function, all of the same keys are processed together, or at least in "groups" of the same key as the reducer works here. So all the reduce function is find the value in that group having the largest count and return the singular item at the matching index.

The result you get is essentially:

```
    { "_id": "err", "value": { "list": [5,6,7], "count":3 }}
    { "_id": "res", "value": { "list": [3,4], "count": 2 }}
    { "_id": "suc", "value": { "list": [2], "count": 1 }}
```

Where mapReduce emits it's final results in "key" order.

Yes the JavaScript evaluation runs a little slower than the aggregation framework, but without the ability to track global variables over the scope of documents it is just something that cannot be done otherwise.